# Android Textview Html Right justified

Tags: android, html, textview

I have some **HTML data to display in Textview**. I know that some of the HTML tags are not supported by Android. So, I am using [third party library](https://github.com/SufficientlySecure/html-textview) to achieve bulletpoints and numbered lists. But, I do also have to **support right alignment**.

Ex :

```
<div style="text-align: right;"><i>Gh</i></div>
```

I'm giving a lot of tries with couple of Html Justification libraries available such as [TextJustify](https://github.com/bluejamesbond/TextJustify-Android) and [Justified](https://github.com/programingjd/justified). But, I'm unable to get the right alignment.

**I cannot fix this with webview in this particular case bcz i'm using it along with recyler.**

Hate HTML support in Android textviews :(.

Can you please help me if you have a solution for this?

Thanks,
Sha

Comment: I had something similar and parsed the elements and assigned them via setting gravity on the textviews

Comment: If some of the text is left aligned and some portion of text is right aligned, is it possible to set different gravities at different parts of textview? Do you have sample code please?

Answer (score 0):

Sorry to answer this way, but I can't add a comment.

A single TextView can only handle one gravity type on the X axis. But it can be set to something like "top|right".

Can you show what you try to achieve ?

Thanks :)